# C segmentation fault prog

Tags: c

I have a problem with segmentation fault. And I am not sure about the arrays. 
I need to get output like this

Here is part of my code. (structure and enumeration must stay unchanged)

EDIT:  second malloc fix, This is only part of my code where I get segmentation fault, warning while compiling: unused variable ‘title’ and segmentation fault while running

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef enum {
    GAME1,
    GAME2,
    GAME3,
} TITLE;


typedef struct abx {
    TITLE **title;  
} ABX;



string[]="ABCACC|ACCBAA|BBCABC"

ABX *abx = (ABX*)malloc(sizeof(ABX));

TITLE **title = (TITLE**)malloc(sizeof(TITLE*));

    width = height = 0;
    while (string[i] !='\0') {
        abx->title[height][width]=(TITLE)malloc(sizeof(TITLE*));

        if(string[i]=='A'){
            abx->title[height][width] = GAME1;
            break;
        }
        if(string[i]=='B'){
            abx->title[height][width] = GAME2;
            break;
        }
        if(string[i]=='C'){
            abx->title[height][width] = GAME3;
            break;
        }
        if (string[i]=='|'){
            height++;
            width = 0;
        } 
        else{
            width++;
        }
        i++;
    }
```

Comment: why are you using a pointer to a pointer for the enum value?

Comment: You are assigning things of two different types, `TITLE` and `TITLE*`, to `abx->title[height][width]`. This cannot possubly be right however you look at it. The compiler ought to issue a warning on one of the assignments. You cannot ignore warnings.

Comment: `TITLE **title = (TITLE**)malloc(sizeof(TITLE*));` meant `title[1][]` only one row. (by width, ditto)

Comment: Not a chance this code compiles. Your first statement for string[i] has no variable i declared at that point and is missing a semi colon at the end. One of your height++ statements is missing the letter 't' in it. Please copy and paste your working code. (Or code that compiles anyways)

Comment: Also, to test the end of the string, you must go while(string[i] != '\0')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef enum {
    GAME1,
    GAME2,
    GAME3,
} TITLE;

typedef struct abx {
    TITLE **title;  
} ABX;

int main(){
    char string[]="ABCACC|ACCBAA|BBCABC";
    ABX *abx = malloc(sizeof(ABX));
    int i, len, w, h, width, height;
    char ch;
    len = width = height = 0;
    for(i=0;(ch=string[i]) != '\0';++i){
        if(ch == '|'){
            ++height;
            if(width<len)
                width = len;
            len = 0;
        } else
            ++len;
    }
    ++height;
    if(width<len)
        width = len;

    abx->title =malloc(height*sizeof(TITLE*));
    for(h=0;h<height;++h)
        abx->title[h]=malloc(width*sizeof(TITLE));

    for(h=w=i=0;string[i]!='\0';++i){
        if(string[i]=='A'){
            abx->title[h][w++] = GAME1;
            continue;
        }
        if(string[i]=='B'){
            abx->title[h][w++] = GAME2;
            continue;
        }
        if(string[i]=='C'){
            abx->title[h][w++] = GAME3;
            continue;
        }
        if (string[i]=='|'){
            ++h;
            w = 0;
        } 
    }
    ...
}
```